Looking for alternative approaches in finding the range of $y=|6x-\lfloor6x+\dfrac73\rfloor|$

What is the range of $y=|6x-\lfloor6x+\dfrac73\rfloor|$?

I have solved this problem by noticing that we can extract the form $u-\lfloor u\rfloor$ from the RHS. Let, $u=6x+\dfrac73$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}$ (as we can imply $x\in\mathbb{R}$ implicitly from the problem):
$$y=|u-\lfloor u\rfloor-\dfrac73|$$
From its graph, we have $u-\lfloor u\rfloor\in [0,1)$  hence $u-\lfloor u\rfloor -\dfrac73\in [-\dfrac73,\dfrac{-4}3)$ and $y\in (\dfrac43,\dfrac73]$.
I'm wondering if one doesn't notice extracting $u-\lfloor u\rfloor$, how this problem can be solved with other approaches.

We can 1/ Show that the inner expression is always negative, so we can remove the absolute sign and simplify things, 2/ Consider what happens at the points of discontinuity.

You can notice that $f(x) = y=\left\vert 6x-\lfloor 6x+\dfrac73\rfloor \right\vert$ is periodical and $1/6$ is a period. Therefore, you can limit the study of $f$ on $[0, 1/6)$. Now
$$g(x) = \lfloor 6x+\dfrac73\rfloor=\begin{cases}
2 & x \in [0,1/9)\\
3 & x \in [1/9, 1/6)
\end{cases}$$
Therefore
$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
\lvert 6x - 2 \rvert = 2(1-3x) & x \in [0,1/9)\\
\lvert 6x - 3 \rvert = 3(1-2x)& x \in [1/9, 1/6)
\end{cases}$$
And finally, the range of $f$ is $(4/3, 7/3]$.
